# Update/Insert column values with another table's group by result in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have an empty table (t1) and I want to insert or update the t1.uid column from another table's (t2) `GROUP BY uid` values.

So far I have tried like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN
       (SELECT uid FROM table2 GROUP BY uid) t2 
    SET t1.uid = t2.uid;
```

but it's not working for me.

N.B. I've got a massive data set for which group by (uid from table-t2) results giving me total 1114732 results which I have to insert/update in t1 table's uid column.

Comment: if a table is empty you cannot update it. You need to do an insert...

Comment: that's why I asked for update or insert :)

Comment: Does t1 have a unique index on uid?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Insert into table1(uid)
      select distinct uid from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

If `table1` is empty, then `UPDATE` is not the correct verb. Would this suit your needs?

```
INSERT into table1 SELECT distinct uid from table2;
```

[INSERT ... SELECT docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: I need to insert the group by results as I got multiple entries in table2 for each uid

Comment: distinct will do the trick. Will select only one time each uid

Comment: see they keyword `distinct` in my query. I believe this fits your requirements.

Comment: @WasidHossain just run the query that nvioli suggested you. It will select once each uid from table2 (no need to do a group by) and each result will be inserted in table . This will work only if you have a table1 with just that column or you have a default value for the other columns